# Multiple constructors in a C++ class

Tags: c++

While looking online at an implementation of vectors for a math engine, i came across this code.

```
class R4DVector3n{

private:

public:
    //x, y and z dimensions
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    //Constructors
    R4DVector3n();
    R4DVector3n(float uX,float uY,float uZ);

    //Destructors
    ~R4DVector3n();

    //Copy Constructors
    R4DVector3n(const R4DVector3n& v);
    R4DVector3n& operator=(const R4DVector3n& v);     
  };
```

What are the reasons / uses for there being multiple constructors for the class, and furthermore what does the author mean by "copy constructors".

Comment: `R4DVector3n& operator=(const R4DVector3n& v);` is not a copy constructor but a [Copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) defined.

Comment: You might want to refer to the early chapters of a good C++ book for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to understand why someone else's code was written in a particular way, please ask *that person*. We can only speculate here, and that sort of thing [is off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). As for "copy constructors", the author presumably means *what the term normally means*; if you aren't familiar with this, you should *follow a C++ tutorial first*. Stack Overflow is not a good place to learn the fundamentals of a language. Finally, please remember that you are supposed to ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: If there is a use case for constructing objects in different ways (from different number/types of arguments) there is a justification for multiple constructors.  Default values for some arguments may be an alternative to overloading in some cases, but doesn't cover all possibilities.   Also most classes that are not explicitly supplied with a copy constructor will be implicitly provided with one (unless that is suppressed somehow), which would give a chicken/egg situation (how to create an instance at all?) if list initialisation isn't possible and there is no other constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the reasons / uses for there being multiple constructors for the class

So that we can create **instances** of that class using different forms. In other words, to **initialize** member variables differently for different objects. For example, for your class `R4DVector3n` we can create instances that uses different constructors depending on the requirements, as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    R4DVector3n obj1; //this creates an object named obj1 of type R4DVector3n using the default constructor

    R4DVector3n obj2(1.1f,2.3f, 4.1f); //this creates an object named obj2 of type R4DVector3n using the Parameterized constructor


    R4DVector3n obj3 = obj2; //this creates object named obj3 of type R4DVector3n using the copy constructor
}
```

In the above example, the object `obj1` is created using the **default constructor**.

The object `obj2` is created using the **parameterized constructor**.

The object `obj3` is created using the **copy constructor**.

---

> what does the author mean by "copy constructors".

From [copy constructor documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor):

> A copy constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is `T&‍`, `const T&‍`, `volatile T&‍`, or `const volatile T&‍`, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values.

This is useful when we want to create an object using another object. So in your code snippet, you have the following copy constructor:

```
R4DVector3n(const R4DVector3n& v); //this is a copy constructor
```

The above statement is a **declaration** for the copy constructor of class
`R4DVector3n`. This was used in my example when i wrote:

```
R4DVector3n obj3 = obj2; //this uses the copy constructor
```

---

Also, note that the following statement:

```
R4DVector3n& operator=(const R4DVector3n& v); //this is copy assignment operator
```

The above statement is a **declaration** for the [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).